# Custom Format for Time in VBA msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, time, format, msgbox

I am facing a problem with VBA.

I am trying to display a msgbox that contains a DATE, however I only want to display the time as "hh:mm".

I am writing the following in my code to try and apply the needed format:

> sum1 = Format(ThisCell, "h:mm")

sum1 is defined as a DATE and ThisCell as a Range.
The format displayed in the msgbox is hh:mm AM/PM.

I have searched thoroughly to find a way to do it, but I could not find a way.

Any thoughts or advice is much appreciated.

Have a good day.

Comment: Format(MyTime, "h:m:s") should give you the format, but with an addition to seconds. Why not just use a string part of the date you are getting. something like substr

Comment: Define sum1 simply as a _String_ and not as _Date_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **String** rather than **Date**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim sum1 As String, ThisCell As Range
    Set ThisCell = ActiveCell
    sum1 = Format(ThisCell, "h:mm")
    MsgBox sum1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sum1 As Date
Dim ThisCell As Range

Set ThisCell = Cells(1, 1) 'Your range goes here
sum1 = Format(ThisCell, "hh:mm am/pm")

MsgBox sum1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

(1) ThisCell refers to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

(2) and ThisCell has been formatted with the custom formatting of "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

(3) It's okay to declare sum1 as string

```
Sub displayTime()

    Dim ThisCell As Range
    Dim sum1 As String

    Set ThisCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    If ThisCell.Value = "" Then
        ThisCell.Value = 0
    End If

    sum1 = Format(ThisCell, "hh:mm am/pm")
    MsgBox sum1

End Sub
```